# android Soft keyboard cover the input box in the webview

Tags: android-webview

I use Webview to load some url  ,there is a input box in the webview .when I  click the input box ,the soft keyboard conver the  input box ,how can i do  to solve

Comment: May have to fix this in js/css if you have access: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39516968/android-keyboard-covering-input-box-even-in-chrome-browser

Answer (score -1):

If you are saying that you are making an application for android and that the soft keyboard is covering an input box when you are testing your application and you would like to fix this issue, you should try the following:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

to the the tag in the manifest and to all your webviews/views. This should fix it and adjust the screen so that the input box isn't covered.

I had a similar issue and I remember looking up on SO and somebody was suggesting this fix and it worked for me. I don't remember the link to that fix :(

Comment: I've come up against this issue just now and while your answer works for edittexts etc it doesn't work for webview I'm afraid