# Android - Keyboard covering input box - Even in Chrome Browser

Tags: javascript, android, css, html

Is there an HTML5 css/js solution to bump up the window content when the soft keyboard appears?

For example, if you open up [duckduckgo.com](https://duckduckgo.com) on an android device and enter text in the input field, when the soft keyboard appears it bumps the content up so it doesn't cover the input box.

Compare that to [shouttag.com](https://shouttag.com) where the keyboard covers half the input box.

This occurs on our webview native app, but it also happens when viewing the site through chrome.

Update 1:

Looks like the fullpage.js api might be the culprit, digging more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here's how I fixed0red the issue, obviously the html anchors are specific to my sitch, so you can change as necessary, the important stuff is in the focus / blur anon fxs.

```
var $fpContainerWrap    = jQuery('.home-wrap .fp-tableCell div');
var $homeWrap           = jQuery('.home-wrap');

var topOffsetRaw = $fpContainerWrap.offset().top - jQuery(window).scrollTop();

var topOffset = '-' + (topOffsetRaw * 1.5) + 'px';

$('input').focus(function() { 

     $("#menu").animate({ top:topOffset }, "fast");
     $homeWrap.animate({ top:topOffset }, "fast");
     $('#section-changer').hide();
});

$('input').blur(function() {

    $("#menu").animate({ top:0 }, "fast");
    $homeWrap.animate({ top:0 }, "fast");
    $('#section-changer').show();
});
```

Comment: Mike, I'm dealing with this same issue now: My web responsive webapp's textarea is being obscured by Android's popup keyboard. Is adjusting the textarea's on-screen position really the only way to do this?

Comment: So far this is the only solution I could find that fixed the problem. If you find something better let me know.